# HttpConstraintElement: maven dependency conflict

Tags: maven, maven-2

I tried to create WebArchieve from my application with help of ShrinkWrap. But even if I don't deploy anything but use:

```
final WebArchive archive = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "archieve.war");
archive.as(ShrinkWrapWebAppContext.class); // throws EXCEPTION!
```

***Exception:***

*class "javax.servlet.HttpConstraintElement"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package*

***What I've tried to do:***
As I understand, I use two jars, both contains HttpConstraintElement. And those maven dependencies have two different versions. So I tried to:

```
$ mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose |grep servlet
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-servlet-wildcard:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-servlet:jar:2.2.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-servlet:jar:2.2.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-servlet:jar:2.2.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-servlet:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.apache.tiles:tiles-servlet:jar:2.2.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.0.0.M4:compile
[INFO]             +- org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet:jar:3.0.0.v201112011016:compile
```

***Questions:***

Does it (maven's result above) means that problem is in *jetty.websocket* and *jetty.orbit* conflict?

If no, how to solve my problem?

If yes, how to resolve the conflict?

Comment: Maybe similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084871/exclude-servlet-api-from-test-scope-maven). There's some useful answers, if I may say so myself :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is the same problem as described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084871/exclude-servlet-api-from-test-scope-maven).

I fixed this as follows:

1. Remove the dependency on `javax.servlet:servlet-api`
2. Explicitly add the dependency on `org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet`, hence fully replacing `javax.servlet:servlet-api`

For a full explanation of this solution you may refer to [my answer on abovementioned question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084871/exclude-servlet-api-from-test-scope-maven#14826498).

Note that you may want to include (whichever) `servlet-api` on scope `provided`. Apache specifically [describes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) this for "Servlet API".