# gradle tests Bouncy Castle ExceptionInInitializerError (conflicting jars?)

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-management

I'm having an error and trying to fix it that I wanted to know if there is any information more about it and how to debug it, the root cause.
I basically wanted to understand more about how I can investigate the error:
"signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package"

For example from this question [Exclude servlet-api from test scope Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084871/exclude-servlet-api-from-test-scope-maven/11085986#11085986) I get that this is basically a problem with different versions of the jar defined in the dependencies.

But when I checked with gradle the dependency scope I don't see any problem that might show up.

I use 2 bouncy castle dependencies. org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-fips and org.bouncycastle:bc-fips

I check with gradle and the dependencies seem what I expect:

```
./gradlew -q dependencyInsight --dependency org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-fips --configuration testRuntimeClasspath
org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-fips:1.0.3
   variant "runtime" [
      org.gradle.status              = release (not requested)
      org.gradle.usage               = java-runtime
      org.gradle.libraryelements     = jar
      org.gradle.category            = library

      Requested attributes not found in the selected variant:
         org.gradle.dependency.bundling = external
         org.gradle.jvm.environment     = standard-jvm
         org.gradle.jvm.version         = 11
   ]

org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-fips:1.0.3
\--- testRuntimeClasspath

./gradlew -q dependencyInsight --dependency org.bouncycastle:bc-fips --configuration testRuntimeClasspath
org.bouncycastle:bc-fips:1.0.1
   variant "runtime" [
      org.gradle.status              = release (not requested)
      org.gradle.usage               = java-runtime
      org.gradle.libraryelements     = jar
      org.gradle.category            = library

      Requested attributes not found in the selected variant:
         org.gradle.dependency.bundling = external
         org.gradle.jvm.environment     = standard-jvm
         org.gradle.jvm.version         = 11
   ]

org.bouncycastle:bc-fips:1.0.1
\--- testRuntimeClasspath

org.bouncycastle:bc-fips:[1.0.0,2.0.0) -> 1.0.1
\--- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-fips:1.0.3
     \--- testRuntimeClasspath
```

Still I get this in the log when I tried to launch my tests:

```
[Test worker] ERROR net.mguenther.kafka.junit.EmbeddedConnect - Failed to deploy connector test-sink-connector.
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.result(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:115)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.util.ConvertingFutureCallback.get(ConvertingFutureCallback.java:107)
    at net.mguenther.kafka.junit.EmbeddedConnect.deployConnector(EmbeddedConnect.java:93)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at net.mguenther.kafka.junit.EmbeddedConnect.start(EmbeddedConnect.java:81)
    at com.abc.kafka.connect.utils.test.kafka.JunitConnectWrapper.start(JunitConnectWrapper.java:59)
    at com.abc.kafka.connect.utils.test.kafka.JunitConnectWrapper.<init>(JunitConnectWrapper.java:52)
    at com.abc.kafka.connect.converters.test.kafka.KafkaConnectCluster.<init>(KafkaConnectCluster.java:40)
    at com.abc.kafka.connect.test.kafka.SnowflakeSinkConnector.<init>(SnowflakeSinkConnector.java:38)
    at com.abc.kafka.connect.integration.SnowflakeSinkConnectorTest.beforeClass(SnowflakeSinkConnectorTest.java:67)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptLifecycleMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:128)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptBeforeAllMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:70)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllMethods$13(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:411)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllMethods(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:409)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:215)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:148)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsStatus.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsStatus.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsStatus$Loader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsStatus.isReady(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.CryptoServicesRegistrar.getDefaultMode(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.CryptoServicesRegistrar.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.ProvSecureHash$MD5.configure(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastleFipsProvider.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastleFipsProvider.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastleFipsProvider.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.EncryptionUtils.parseEncryptedPrivateKey(EncryptionUtils.java:30)
    at com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.InternalUtils.createProperties(InternalUtils.java:151)
    at com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeConnectionServiceFactory$SnowflakeConnectionServiceBuilder.setProperties(SnowflakeConnectionServiceFactory.java:58)
    at com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector.validate(SnowflakeSinkConnector.java:243)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.validateConnectorConfig(AbstractHerder.java:471)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.lambda$validateConnectorConfig$2(AbstractHerder.java:367)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.bouncycastle.util.test.TestRandomBigInteger"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:1151)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:906)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1015)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsDSA$DsaProvider.createEngine(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsDSA$DsaProvider.createEngine(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsDSA.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 23 more
```

So my question is how can I investigate on my class path where the bouncy castle dependency is being resolved?
Or how could I verify the differences between the packages signature information.
Thank you for any feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this error by looking in my `tomcat/lib` for any jars containing the class mentioned in the stack trace, in my case I did this with:

```
for f in *.jar; do echo "$f: "; unzip -l $f | grep -i 'org.glassfish.jersey.inject.hk2.RequestContext*'; done
```

This let me find and then remove one the one two conflicting jars.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I don't have a clear solution but I found the problem for me.
I had 2 jar's in my path that implemented the same class.
bcprov-jdk18on-1.72.jar and bc-fips-1.0.1.jar

They somehow seem incompatible but they are inherited dependencies of some packages I use so I just excluded "bcprov" but it's not really an answer to be honest